# ghidra scripting: how to distinguish between function and global symbol

Tags: ghidra

I have a following program:

```
int b2[4];
int foo()
{
  static int b2[10];
  b2[5] = 4;
}
int main()
{
  static int b2[10];
  int b[5];
  b[0] = 1;
  b2[9] = 4;
  int *ptr = b;
  int c = *(ptr + 10);
  foo();
  return 0;
}
```

I want to distinguish between different b2 arrays defined in functions foo, main and globally. I can collect all the symbols using:

```
symbols = set(currentProgram.getSymbolTable().getAllSymbols(True))
    for s in symbols:
        print(s.getName())
```

But, there is no way to distinguish between static (in functional namespace) and global symbols.

Ghidra GUI shows me something like:
b2.1913 <- main , b2.1917 <- foo, b2 <- global.

Thus I can easily distinguish between these symbols using GUI.

Thanks in advanced for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Symbol` object has a couple different ways you could go about this. Here are a few options.

```py
symbols = set(currentProgram.getSymbolTable().getAllSymbols(True))
for s in symbols:
    if s.getName() == "b2":
        print(s.getName(), s.getName(True), s.getParentSymbol().getName(), s.getParentNamespace())
```

Output:

```
GetSymbolType.py> Running...
(u'b2', u'b2', u'global', Global)
(u'b2', u'foo()::b2', u'foo()', foo())
(u'b2', u'main::b2', u'main', main)
```

Explanation:

1. `s.getName(true)` - Includes the parent namespace in the output (you'll notice that for global symbols, this has no effect)
2. `s.getParentSymbol().getName()`, name of the parent `Symbol`, which will be the namespace `Symbol` that contains `s`
3. `s.getParentNamespace()` - return the parent `Namespace` object

More details in the [API docs](https://ghidra.re/ghidra_docs/api/ghidra/program/model/symbol/Symbol.html).